# DRM copy protection for doc files

Tags: windows, ms-word, drm

Does anybody know of a solution to copy protect ms word documents. We need to limit the opening 
of the document to the machine to which it was downloaded. Ideally we will have license server
that can issue licence tokens per client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Office has incorporated an information rights management (IRM) since Office 2003.  You can find Microsoft's notes on the IRM implementations for [Office 2003](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/information-rights-management-in-microsoft-office-2003-HA001039789.aspx?CTT=3), [2007](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/information-rights-management-in-the-2007-microsoft-office-system-HA010102918.aspx), and [2010](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/information-rights-management-in-office-2010-HA010354260.aspx).  For users without a DRM server, Microsoft provides a free service using Windows Live IDs.

AegisDRM offers a commercial solution, [Protector add-in for MS Office (PaM)](http://www.aegisdrm.com/digitalrightsmanagement/benefits/Control_and_protect_word_excel_and_other_office_documents.htm), but no direct information about pricing is listed.